# Importing a .csv to ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-desktop

I'm trying to import a .csv file to ArcMap which has more than one feature related to a single x, y coordinate. It doesn't seem to like it - can anyone help with the formatting?

e.g.

```
ID  name    x   y   veg name
1   swamp 1 208229  920604  green sprouts
2   swamp 1 208229  920604  red onions
3   swamp 1 208229  920604  cabbage
4   swamp 2 257589  935259  green sprouts
5   swamp 2 257589  935259  lentils
```

Comment: If it is a CSV, where are the commas?

Comment: I just created a CSV with the same data and column names and imported it into ArcMap 10.1 with no problems.  Please provide more information about how you are creating (or acquiring) the csv and importing it into ArcMap.

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe, I suspect that he's got a csv and that he just copied the cells from excel and pasted them into his question.  I just tried doing the same thing and I get the exact same formatting he did. That would explain the lack of commas.

Answer (score 5):

That appears to be a fixed width text file, not a CSV. It will be much easier to import into ArcGIS if you first save it as a CSV using Excel. Recommended steps:

1. Edit the text file, renaming **ID** to **ID_Num** and **veg name** to **veg_name** then save
2. Open the text file in Excel as a fixed width file. Carefully line up the columns - Excel will see "swamp 1" from the **Name** column as two different columns (as the data currently appears).
3. Save the file as a CSV
4. Add the CSV to ArcMap.

*Edit:* If the file is already CSV-formatted, make sure you change **veg name** to something that doesn't have a space (e.g. **veg_name**) before adding it to ArcMap. If you don't, Arc will complain about an invalid field name.

Comment: Is ID a reserved name? (Just asking because you suggest to change it.)

Comment: Not in Arc. Excel assumes a CSV or text file that starts with ID is a certain type of file, then will complain that it doesn't match the expected parameters of the file type. Sometimes Excel will continue to work with the file, sometimes it won't.

Comment: Add the csv to arcmap. How do you do it??